# how to find functions in a vba reference library

Tags: excel, function, vba, object, reference

I'm using Excel 2010 and I see libraries that I would like to use under Tools->References but I cannot find documentation online. VBA sees the new objects and functions after referencing the library. How can I see that list of function prototypes and objects?

Comment: In the object explorer

Answer (score 2):

Goto:

View -> Object Browser

From there you can select a specific library and view the functions available:

[image: Object Browser]